# CSS how to center ::after pseudo elem

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centering an `::after` CSS pseudo element.  The main element is an image:

- the image should be in the center of the page
- the `::after` pseudo element which shows the image caption, should be overlaid in the center of the image.

Here is what I have:

```css
#frame {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: black;
  &: after {
    content: 'Caption overlay';
    color: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <svg width="200" height="200">...</svg>
</div>
```

The image frame is correctly centered on the page, but its caption is not centered over the image. Instead it  is at the bottom right corner.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAZwjx?editors=1100#0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it by adding `text-align:center;` and also `position: fixed;` to your `:after` pseudo element.

```
#frame {
    position: fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: black;
    &:after {
        position:fixed;
        content: 'Caption overlay';
        color: white;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

Compiled CSS version is:

```
#frame {
    position: fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: black;
}

#frame:after {
    position:fixed;
    content: 'Caption overlay';
    color: white;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's almost perfect. Is there a way to force the whole caption on one line even if it overflows the div?

Comment: Yes thats possible. To do that add the white-space: nowrap; to the :after pseudo element.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use svg's own [text element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) along with [text-anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor).

Also, what ever the method, `white-space: nowrap` should keep the text in one line.

```
<div id="frame">
  <svg width="200" height="200">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="75" stroke="green" stroke-width="15"/>
    <text x="100" y="100" text-anchor="middle">Caption Overlay</text>
  </svg>
</div>

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: visible;
}
text {
  fill: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: woah that's really cool. The solution as-is doesn't meet my first requirement in the OP but it can be adjusted to do so.  +1

Comment: Is there an easy way to make the SVG's background transparent?

Comment: I know. It just allows you to do a lot more with the text. I'm pretty sure there are limitations to the kind of things you can add in a `pseudo` element's `content` property.

Comment: And yes. Remove the background color on the `#frame`. and then add `circle{fill: transparent}`

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:absolute` to your `::after pseudo element`.

```
 &:after {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    ........
    ........
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that. The caption is not centered as I'd like because of a line break; see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAZrbj?editors=1100#0  .  How can I force it on one line even if it overflows the div?  That way it will look centered

Comment: @BeetleJuice text-align:center; add this.

Comment: The line break remains

Comment: @BeetleJuice width:100%;

Comment: Nice idea but that doesn't force all on one line. It only worked because the caption was short. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAZrbj?editors=1100#0

Comment: @BeetleJuice it's in one line but now it overflows your svg width as it is of 200px;

Comment: I understand that. Please take another look at my first comment. I asked "*How can I force it on one line even if it overflows the div?*"  Is it not possible in your opinion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123046/discussion-between-frnt-and-beetlejuice).

Comment: @leli was able to force everything on one line with `white-space:nowrap` , so I feel I should select the other answer. Still thank you very much for trying to help me figure it out

Comment: @BeetleJuice No problem in the end we need solution, but still it overflows   really long content :-) Welcome.